# unexpected slice append behaviour

Tags: go

I encountered weird behaviour in go code today: when I append `elements` to `slice` in loop and then try to create new `slices` based on the result of the loop, last `append` overrides `slices` from previous `appends`.

In this particular example it means that `sliceFromLoop` `j`,`g` and `h` slice's last element are not `100`,`101` and `102` respectively, but...always `102`!

Second example - `sliceFromLiteral` behaves as expected.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func create(iterations int) []int {
    a := make([]int, 0)
    for i := 0; i < iterations; i++ {
        a = append(a, i)
    }
    return a
}

func main() {
    sliceFromLoop()
    sliceFromLiteral()

}

func sliceFromLoop() {
    fmt.Printf("** NOT working as expected: **\n\n")
    i := create(11)
    fmt.Println("initial slice: ", i)
    j := append(i, 100)
    g := append(i, 101)
    h := append(i, 102)
    fmt.Printf("i: %v\nj: %v\ng: %v\nh:%v\n", i, j, g, h)
}

func sliceFromLiteral() {
    fmt.Printf("\n\n** working as expected: **\n")
    i := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    fmt.Println("initial slice: ", i)
    j := append(i, 100)
    g := append(i, 101)
    h := append(i, 102)
    fmt.Printf("i: %v\nj: %v\ng: %v\nh:%v\n", i, j, g, h)
}
```

link to play.golang:
https://play.golang.org/p/INADVS3Ats

After some reading, digging and experimenting I found that this problem is originated in `slices` referencing the same underlaying `array`  values and can be solved by copying `slice` to new one before appending anything, however it looks quite... hesitantly.

**What's the idomatic way for creating many new slices based on old ones and not worrying about changing values of old slices?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't assign `append` to anything other than itself.

As you mention in the question, the confusion is due to the fact that `append` both changes the underlying array and returns a new slice (since the length might be changed). You'd imagine that it copies that backing array, but it doesn't, it just allocates a new `slice` object that points at it. Since `i` never changes, all those appends keep changing the value of `backingArray[12]` to a different number.

Contrast this to `append`ing to an array, which allocates a new literal array every time.

So yes, you need to copy the slice before you can work on it.

```
func makeFromSlice(sl []int) []int {
    result := make([]int, len(sl))
    copy(result, sl)
    return result
}

func main() {
    i := make([]int, 0)
    for ii:=0; ii<11; ii++ {
        i = append(i, ii)
    }
    j := append(makeFromSlice(i), 100)  // works fine
}
```

---

The slice literal behavior is explained because a new array ***is*** allocated if the append would exceed the `cap` of the backing array. This has nothing to do with slice literals and everything to do with the internals of how exceeding the cap works.

```
a := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
fmt.Printf("len(a) %d, cap(a) %d\n", a, len(a), cap(a))
// len(a) 7, cap(a) 7

b := make([]int, 0)
for i:=1; i<8, i++ {
    b = append(b, i)
}  // b := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
// len(b) 7, cap(b) 8

b = append(b, 1)  // any number, just so it hits cap

i := append(b, 100)
j := append(b, 101)
k := append(b, 102)  // these work as expected now
```

Comment: This official blog on slices is worth a read in the same conext: https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro#TOC_5.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a copy of a slice, there's no other way to do it other than, copying the slice. You should almost never assign the result of `append` to a variable other than the first argument of `append`. It leads to hard to find bugs, and will behave differently depending on whether the slice has the required capacity or not.

This isn't a commonly needed pattern, but as with all things of this nature if you need to repeate a few lines of code multiple times, then you can use a small helper function:

```
func copyAndAppend(i []int, vals ...int) []int {
    j := make([]int, len(i), len(i)+len(vals))
    copy(j, i)
    return append(j, vals...)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/J99_xEbaWo

Answer (score 0):

There is also a little bit simpler way to implement `copyAndAppend` function:

```
func copyAndAppend(source []string, items ...string) []string {
    l := len(source)
    return append(source[:l:l], items...)
}
```

Here we just make sure that source has no available capacity and so copying is forced.

Comment: Interesting idea. There is one catch though: if `items` is empty, then the same slice (not a copy) is returned: https://play.golang.org/p/_6e4DMqB-CQ